# Error after importing Pushwoosh for iOS PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova, pushwoosh

I am working on my iOS PhoneGap-App. I have  downloaded the plugin with following command: phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/shaders/pushwoosh-phonegap-build-plugin.git from github in the project-folder.

When I want to run the application in XCode I get 3 same errors in the PushNotification.m - File.

In Row 45,225,348 this error comes: No visible @interface for 'CordovaWrapperViewController' declare the selector 'getCommandInstance:'

[image]

I don't know, what I did wrong, so I am glad of any solution I get!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of reasons it could happen, but generally it's saying that at the line of code it flags, it doesn't see any evidence that the selector you are referencing is in the interface of the type it thinks the object has.

In this example,

[No visible interface error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574597/no-visible-interface-error)

They declared operandStack with the wrong type.

In this one

http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3312

They had a typo in the selector name